# Bold certain words of the column output in Oracle BI publisher rtf template

Tags: oracle, rtf, bi-publisher

I have a requirement to bold the word "**and**" in Oracle BI publisher report.

I am pulling the data from the a table column in the database which has a long string and want to bold the word "and" in that string.
I tried to put html tags in the database around the word "**and**" ,but it is not working. How can I get it bold?

Comment: I spent time trying to find a way to highlight different groups of words in a paragraph (basically the same thing) and didn't find a solution. We ended up changing how the xml was generated (yuck).